# Will my node.js lock up while comparing lists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, performance, cpu

So, basically i have 2 lists on a node.js app that i'm planning, one of them i get from a database and the other from copying the names of files on a server and storing that inside a list.

The problem is: both of them have ~750000 strings each, and i need to search for each string in one inside the other.

I am pretty new to node, so i'm wondering, will my app lock itself to other users while comparing the lists, with it being single threaded and all? comparing two huge lists like these seems pretty cpu intensive to me.

Comment: If you build them into the keys of an object (i.e. put them in a hash table) or use a suitable library you could reduce your search from exponential to linear. Also, this may be a good job for the database - maybe create a temporary table and do the comparison in sql?

Comment: I was thinking maybe write 2 .json files and comparing them.Would that be a good idea?

Comment: If you are comparing them with the same Node.js process, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of how you are comparing the lists and how your application is built, but generally yes. For example, this code would block execution:

```js
server.on("request", (req, res)=>{
    // This function will not be called while the comparasion is running.
    // Requests will have to wait until the call stack empties (until nothing
    // is running).
}
compareLists();
```

Maybe you should take a look at [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) in order to make your Node.js application multi-threaded, or you could just execute another Node.js script in parallel with [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Also, see [this guide about the JavaScript event loop](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/).